# How to create a lua table from a string?

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have a c function, used to return a table to lua, but the table is created from a string, not lua_newtable, how to do this?

```
int GetTable(lua_State* L)
{
    //this string is generated at runtime, so i can not use lua_newtable
    const char* TableFromStr = "{a = 123, b = 456, d = {x = 1, y = 9} }";
    //i want to push the table to the top stack
    luaL_loadstring(L, TableFromStr);
    //return 1 table, lua code can get the table
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If `luaL_loadstring` something you're trying to implement? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Concatenate `"return "` with `TableFromStr` and invoke `luaL_dostring`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `luaL_dostring`

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dostring

If you're using Lua 5.1 make sure `luaL_dostring` is correctly defined. See: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-04/msg00218.html

> In Lua 5.1, `luaL_dostring` is defined as `luaL_loadstring(L, s) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)`
>
> and so it ignores returns.
>
> Try this:
>
> ```
> #undef luaL_dostring
> #define luaL_dostring(L,s)    \   (luaL_loadstring(L, s) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
> ```

It's possible that you will also have to prepend your string with `return`

Comment: Suggestion: Add the relevant content (code example)  from the 2nd link directly into your answer.  Leaving the link intact is fine to provide a reference of where the example code came from, but the link by itself may disappear at some point, rendering your answer less useful.